# How can I copy GPS information from one iPhone photo to another?

Tags: iphone, photos, gps

I have a large number of photos on my iPhone that were taken at an event, but only some of them have GPS information. The ones missing the information were airdropped to me by other attendees without the setting to retain this data. I want to copy the GPS information from a photo that has it (e.g., that I took) to the photos that don't have it. I have not been able to find a way to do this. Is there one?

I want the GPS information to be added to the image files themselves rather than being stored in some other way (as would be the case if I added the information using Google Photos' "Add location" feature).

I'm running iOS 15.5 on an iPhone SE (2nd generation). Any solution based on an iOS app or on something in the cloud should be okay. I don't have access to a Mac. I have a Windows machine.

Comment: [EXIF Viewer](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/exif-viewer-by-fluntro/id944118456?l=en) for iOS let you add GPS location data (or edit any other EXIF data) to multiple selected photos.

Comment: [EXIFTools](https://exiftool.org/) is option on Windows, Linux, Macos to copy this data between different pictures. [jExifToolGui](https://hvdwolf.github.io/jExifToolGUI/) offers a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

- Open the photo or video you want to copy the metadata from on your iPhone.
- Click the (i) in a circle to show the metadata.
- Long press on the date-time and choose "Copy Location".
- Open the photo or video you want to copy the metadata ***to***.
- Click the (i) in a circle to show the metadata.
- Long press on the date-time and choose "Paste Location".
- Repeat for the "Date & Time" if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with any image metadata editor program that allows batch editing. For iOS, see [Metadata Pro](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/metadata-pro/id835505449?uo=4) (I haven't tried this one and there are also other such apps for iOS as well as Windows, so look and choose). You can also do this with the iOS Photos app but only one photo at a time (Open the photo, tap the "i" button and edit). For Mac users, [SnipTag](https://www.sniptagapp.com) is an EXIF and IPTC metadata editor; there are also others.

Comment: I will look at Metadata Pro, but as regards the iOS Photos app, how can I _copy_ the GPS information from one photo and _paste_ it into another one?

Comment: With iOS Photos app, you have to input manually.

Comment: So how do I view the precise GPS location of a photo? The "i" button shows a map, but it doesn't give precise coordinates. If I copy the location by long-pressing on the map, I can't find a way to paste that into the location box for a photo with no location information.

Comment: I've created a shortcut you can use. This uses "Get Details of Images" to get the image location and copies it as coordinates to your clipboard. You can then paste this in the search box in iOS photos. https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/4a1e6dc3c73645618e72b7bf67127050

Comment: I modified Ezekiel's shortcut above to make produce a link to apple maps where it shows a pin and the name of the photo.  https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/8534154ca348489daf43cfff4d88116b